# Simple Class - Is it a Memory Leak?

Tags: java, memory-leaks

I've a very simple class which has one integer variable. I just print the value of variable 'i' to the screen and increment it, and make the thread sleep for 1 second. When I run a profiler against this method, the memory usage increases slowly even though I'm not creating any new variables. After executing this code for around 16 hours, I see that the memory usage had increased to 4 MB (initially 1 MB when I started the program). I'm a novice in Java. Could any one please help explain where am I going wrong, or why the memory usage is gradually increasing even when there are no new variables created? Thanks in advance.

I'm using netbeans 7.1 and its profiler to view the memory usage.

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            int i = 1;
            while(true)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
                i++;
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            }
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            System.out.print(ex.toString());
        }
    }
```

Initial memory usage when the program started : 1569852 Bytes.

Memory usage after executing the loop for 16 hours : 4095829 Bytes

[image: Screen shot of the issue i'm facing with the code in this post]

Comment: Why don't you get a "real" profiler or take a heap dump to check what is consuming all the memory? I bet a lot of char arrays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not necessarily a memory leak.  When the GC runs, the objects that are allocated (I presume) in the `System.out.println(i);` statement will be collected.  A memory leak in Java is when memory fills up with useless objects that *can't* be reclaimed by the GC.

The `println(i)` is using `Integer.toString(int)` to convert the `int` to a String, and that is allocating a new `String` each time.  That is not a leak, because the String will become unreachable and a candidate for GC'ing once it has been copied to the output buffer.

Other possible sources of memory allocation:

- Thread.sleep could be allocating objects under the covers.
- Some private JVM thread could be causing this.
- The "java agent" code that the profiler is using to monitor the JVM state could be causing this.  It has to assemble and send data over a socket to the profiler application, and that could well involve allocating Java objects.  It may also be accumulating stuff in the JVM's heap or non-heap memory.

But it doesn't really matter so long as the space *can* be reclaimed if / when the GC runs.  If it can't, then you may have found a JVM bug or a bug in the profiler that you are using.  (Try replacing the loop with one very long sleep and see if the "leak" is still there.)  And it probably doesn't matter if this is a slow leak caused by profiling ... because you don't normally run production code with profiling enabled for that long.

---

Note: calling `System.gc()` is not guaranteed to cause the GC to run.  Read the javadoc.

Comment: Hi Stephen, thanks for the detailed explanation. I agree even if the System.gc() is run, it may not cause the GC to run, however one concern I have is, if i comment out the System.out.println(i), and just run the while loop with the increment statement, and the thread sleep also, the consumed memory is increasing.

Comment: @VinaySathyanarayana - I gave you some possible explanations for that.  See the bullet points.  IMO, the most likely one is that it is an artefact of the profiler itself.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any memory leak in this code. You should see how Garbage collector in Java works and at its strategies. Very basically speaking GC won't clean up until it is needed - as indicated in particular strategy.

You can also try to call `System.gc()`.

The objects are created probably in the two Java Core functions.

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the text displayed in the console, and the size of the integer (a little bit).

Java print functions use 8-bit ASCII, therefor 56000 prints of a number, at 8 bytes each char will soon rack up memory.

Comment: No. Its not due to the text being displayed in the console. If I remove the println and run the program, still the memory usage continues to increase. You can check it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Follow this tutorial to find your memory leak: [Analyzing Memory Leak in Java Applications using VisualVM](http://rejeev.blogspot.de/2009/04/analyzing-memory-leak-in-java.html). You have to make a snapshot of your application at the start and another one after some time. With VisualVM you can do this and compare these to snapshots.

Comment: I tried to run the gc as well. 
1. The memory usage did not come down. Even though I executed the gc, it may run when needed. 
2. Suppose if I have a bigger program, how do I ascertain whether it is a memory leak in the program or a gc time interval issue?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the JVM upper memory limit so low that the possible leak will cause it to run out of memory.

If the used memory hits that limit and continues to work away happily then garbage collection is doing its job.

If instead it bombs, then you have a real problem...

Answer (score 0):

This does not seem to be leak as the graphs of the profiler also tell. The graph drops sharply after certain intervals i.e. when GC is performed. It would have been a leak had the graph kept climbing steadily. The heap space remaining after that must be used by the thread.sleep() and also (as mentioned in one of answers above) from the some code of the profiler.

You can try running VisualVM located at `%JAVA_HOME%/bin` and analyzing your application therein. It also gives you the option of performing GC at will and many more options.

I noted that the more features of VisualVM I used more memory was being consumed (upto 10MB). So this increase, it has to be from your profiler as well but it still is not a leak as space is reclaimed on GC.

Answer (score -1):

Does this occur without the printlns? In other words, perhaps keeping the printlns displayed on the console is what is consuming the memory.

Comment: Yes, this does occur with out printing the variable value to the screen.

Comment: If it is the System.out.println() method then try calling the garbage collector ("System.gc();")after the call to System.out.println

Comment: -1: Not an answer, but a question about the question.  This should have been a comment.

Comment: @Don Roby No, it is a suggestion for what is causing the problem and a solution given the possible result of his answer of whether it occurred without the printlns. Stupid down vote.